# Why border-radius not working in tcpdf and how to display the text in one line?

Tags: html, css, pdf, tcpdf, border-radius

I am using tcpdf and I have to display the circle and text should be in one in the pdf. I tried below code but `border-radius` is not working

I am getting below output

[image]

My expected output is
[image]

This is the code I am using

```
$html='<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="20px">
            <tr>
            <td><p><div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:#58d68d;border-radius:50px;margin-right:05px;"></div> Demo1</p></td>
            <td><p><div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:#f5b041;border-radius:50px;margin-right:05px"></div> Demo2</p></td>
            <td><p><div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:#e74c3c;border-radius:50px;margin-right:05px"></div> Demo3</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>';
```

Comment: `<div>` is not a valid child of `<p>`, so your HTML is invalid. Invalid HTML cannot be expected to work correctly. `<span>` may work instead, provided to add `display:inline-block` to allow it to be sized.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I aggreed. I used span but then I am not getting my color box.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to change in border-radius: 50px --> 50%;

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="20px">
        <tr>
        <td><p><div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:#58d68d;border-radius:50%;margin-right:05px;"></div> Demo1</p></td>
        <td><p><div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:#f5b041;border-radius:50%;margin-right:05px"></div> Demo2</p></td>
        <td><p><div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:#e74c3c;border-radius:50%;margin-right:05px"></div> Demo3</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: border-radius : 50% ; Not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to have the 'Demo' texts in each coloured section? If so, consider the following changes:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="20px">
<tr>
    <td><span style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:#58d68d;border-radius:50px;margin-right:05px;padding:2em;"> Demo1</span></td>
    <td><span style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:#f5b041;border-radius:50px;margin-right:05px;padding:2em;">Demo2</span></td>
    <td><span style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:#e74c3c;border-radius:50px;margin-right:05px;padding:2em;">Demo3</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Remove `<p>` and `<div>` and replace it with `<span>`, then control the amount of padding around each text using `padding`.

Comment: No, I don't want to display my text inside the color box. Also, padding, margin, and border-radius will not work in tcpdf.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll make the necessary changes. Do you want the text on the right of each colour?

Comment: Yes, I need a text on the right side of each color. I can achieve this using flex, table-cell, inline-block, etc. but there are some limitation in tcpdf

Comment: Gotcha. If I recall correctly you can use lists in tcpdf, but each bullet point size is fixed unless you can replace it with a picture. Changing each colour would be fine:

    `...
    <td><ul><li style="fcolor: green;"><spancolor: black">Demo1</span></li></ul></td>
    ...`